# Entity-Framework using expressions to build global and reusable filter/query-rules

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression, dry

Given the following linq-query:

```
var query1 = dbContext.MainTable.Where(m => m.MainId == _mainId).SelectMany(sub => sub.SubTable1)
    .Select(sub1 => new
    {
        sub1.CategoryName,
        VisibleDivisions = sub1.SubTable2
            .Where(sub2 => sub2.Status == "Visible")
            .Select(sub2 => new 
            { 
                /* select only what needed */   
            })
    });
```

Starting from my main-table, I want to get all sub1's selected together with all the sub2's related to the sub1.
The query works as expected, generating a single query which will hit the database.

My question is regarding the inner `Where`-part, as of this filter will be used at several other parts in the application. So I would like to have this "visible-rule" defined at a single place (DRY-principle).

As of the Where is expecting an `Func<SubTable2, bool>` I have written the following property

```
public static Expression<Func<SubTable2, bool>> VisibleOnlyExpression => sub2 => sub2.Status == "Visible";
```

and changed my query to

```
var query1 = dbContext.MainTable.Where(m => m.MainId == _mainId).SelectMany(sub => sub.SubTable1)
    .Select(sub1 => new
    {
        sub1.CategoryName,
        VisibleDivisions = sub1.SubTable2
            .Where(VisibleOnlyExpression.Compile())
            .Select(sub2 => new 
            { 
                /* select only what needed */   
            })
    });
```

This throws me an exception, stating `Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025.`.
I already tried changing to `.Where(VisibleOnlyExpression.Compile())` with the same error.

I know that this is because `EntityFramework` is trying to transalte this into `SQL` which it can not.

My question is: How can I have my "filter-rules" defined at a single place (DRY) in code but have the still usable in `Where`-, `Select`-, ... -clauses which can be used on `IQueryable` as well as on `ICollection` for inner (sub-)queries?

I would love to be able to write something like:

```
var query = dbContext.MainTable
    .Where(IsAwesome)
    .SelectMany(s => s.SubTable1.Where(IsAlsoAwesome))
    .Select(sub => new 
    { 
        Sub1sub2s = sub.SubTable2.Where(IsVisible),
        Sub2Mains = sub.MainTable.Where(IsAwesome)
    });
```

whereas the `IsAwesome`-rule is called first on `IQueryable<MainTable>` to get only awesome main-entries and later on `ICollection<MainTable>` in the sub-select to fetch only awesome main-entries related to a specific SubTable2-entry. But the rule - defining a MainTable-entry as awesome - will be the same, no matter where I call/filter for it.

I guess the solution will need the use of expression-trees and how they can be manipulated, so they will be translatable to plain SQL but I don't get the right idea or point to start with.

Comment: You'll need some 3rd party library like [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

Comment: Just tried with LinqKit. It throws the same exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can get something close to what are you asking for using the [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) `AsExpandable` and `Invoke` extension methods like this:

```
var isAvesome = IsAwesome;
var isAlsoAwesome = IsAlsoAwesome;
var isVisible = IsVisible;

var query = dbContext.MainTable
    .AsExpandable()
    .Where(mt => isAwesome.Invoke(mt))
    .SelectMany(s => s.SubTable1.Where(st1 => isAlsoAwesome.Invoke(st1)))
    .Select(sub => new 
    { 
        Sub1sub2s = sub.SubTable2.Where(st2 => isVisible.Invoke(st2)),
        Sub2Mains = sub.MainTable.Where(mt => isAwesome.Invoke(mt))
    });
```

I'm saying close because first you need to pull all the expressions needed into variables, otherwise you'll get the famous EF "Method not supported" exception. And second, the invocation is not so concise as in your wish. But at least it allows you to reuse the logic.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK what you are trying to do should be perfectly possible:

```
// You forgot to access ".Status" in your code.
// Also you don't have to use "=>" to initialize "IsVisible". Use the regular "=".
public static Expression<Func<SubTable2, bool>> IsVisible = sub2 =>
    sub2.Status == "Visible";

...

VisibleDivisions = sub1
    .SubTable2
    // Don't call "Compile()" on your predicate expression. EF will do that.
    .Where(IsVisibleOnly)
    .Select(sub2 => new 
        { 
            /* select only what needed */   
        })
```

Comment: This will fail in the inner select as the `Where` need a `Func<SubTable2, bool>` instead of `Expression<Func<SubTable2, bool>>`. That's why I tried calling `Compile()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would prepare extension method like below:

```
public static IQueryable<SubTable2> VisibleOnly(this IQueryable<SubTable2> source)
{
    return source.Where(s => s.Status == "Visible");
}
```

An then you can use it in that way:

```
var query = dbContext.Table.VisibleOnly().Select(...)
```

Comment: But wouldn't this select all (`*`) from `Table` in the generated SELECT-statement? I only want to receive (select) the values I need

Comment: I just omited Select part. You can select any values you want, i.e. `Select(a=>a.Property)` or append another expression to it. You can even cascade: `dbContext.Table.VisibleOnly1().Select(a => new { NewProp = a.Property.VisibleOnly()` as long as underlying type match SubTable2

Comment: The inner part `{NewProp = a.Property.VisibleOnly()}` will not work as a.Property is `ICollection`. Calling `a.Property.AsQueryable().VisibleOnly()` will compile. But then it throws `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'ActiveOnly()'`

Comment: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'ActiveOnly()'` - do you have `ActiveOnly' extension method defined? You can also try to extend ICollection instead of IQueryable.

Comment: This will fail on the outer select, as this is of type `IQueryable` and not `IEnumerable`. This would end up in 2 methods doing the same (breaking DRY).

Comment: If you really need one for everything, you can write extension to `IEnumerable<T>`, i.e. `public static IEnumerable<SubTable2> VisibleOnly(this IEnumerable<SubTable2> source)`